# Customize options in form select multiple [Symfony2]

Tags: forms, symfony, select, twig

It's been a long time i'm looking for solution about my problem...
When you make a select multiple in Sf2, it render like this

```
<select multiple="multiple">            
    <option value="1" selected="selected">something</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">something else</option>
</select>
```

I want to find something to add a checkbox before each option.
Like this, user have to click on checkbox to select it.

Here's my code in my form builder :

```
->add('projNats', EntityType::class, array(
          'class' => 'ITBundle:Nature',
          'label' => 'nature',
          'choice_label' => 'lib',
          'multiple' => true, 
          'required' => false))
```

Ideally, i would like something like this but it doesn't work...

```
{% for nat in form.projNats %}
  <input type="checkbox"> {{ form_widget(nat) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to custom the choices widget but i didn't manage to do this.

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        <input type="checkbox"> {{ form_widget(child) }}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

Maybe it's too hard or simply impossible to do it with symfony and i should use some javascript...

Comment: Did you try the [`expanded`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#expanded) option?

Comment: ok now i have what i wanted but I cant custom the option like i want. If i want to have an option per row... how should i do ?

Comment: This is a different question from your original post. You should probably post a new question (I think it's better than editing this one, the goal is too different). Whatever you decide, you should put the rendered HTML in your question because it will help to define CSS rules.

Comment: ok thx for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable the [`expanded` option](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/entity.html#expanded) in order to display checkboxes:

> **expanded**
>
> type: `boolean` default: `false`
>
> If set to true, radio buttons or checkboxes will be rendered
>   (depending on the multiple value). If false, a select element will be
>   rendered.

So you should use something like this:

```
->add('projNats', EntityType::class, array(
      'class' => 'ITBundle:Nature',
      'label' => 'nature',
      'choice_label' => 'lib',
      'multiple' => true,
      'expanded' => true,
      'required' => false))
```

Comment: Hi! I can't find out why you set 'choice_label' => 'lib'. Any Symfony reference to dig in?

Comment: @NormaN it was in the question. It's used to display a property in the choice field: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label